# How to fix "To log on to this remote console session, you must have administrative permissions on this computer."?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 2003 server box that was removed from the domain and re-added to the domain.

That is when a domain user lost its access to "Microsoft Remote Desktop" with this message:

> To log on to this remote console session, you must have
>   administrative permissions on this computer.

I configured this > 10 years ago and I can't remember the way to set this up.

Searching for the exact error message doesn't bring a solution. Not with Google neither with Bing.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The domain user needed to be re-added to the local group of admins.

1. Login to the box with an account with administrative permissions
2. Computer Management (Local)
3. System Tools
4. Local Users and Groups
5. **Groups** (<- not "Users")
6. Administrators
7. `[ Add... ]`
8. ... finally select the domain user account here
9. `[ OK ]` (of course)

Comment: Thanks to https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/90608-how-do-i-allow-a-domain-user-to-have-local-admin-rights-to-just-his-pc for pointing me in to the right direction.